# List Items Transitioning

Tags: html, list, css-transitions

I have a header that when hovered over will move the block below (#Container) downwards, opening the space for a menu that will slowly appear also on hover over header.

**CSS**

```
#MenuWrapper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 979px;
    height: 190px;
    top: 155px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: #FFF 1px solid;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 8s;
    }

#Header:hover + #Container {
    top: 195px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    }

#Header:hover #MenuWrapper {
    opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="WrapperPrincipal">

  <h id="Header">
    <ul id="MenuWrapper">
      <li id="Item-L">Login</li>
      <li id="Item-R">Register</li>
      <li id="Item-D">Download</li>
    </ul>
  </h>

  <div id="Container">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the items to appear first, but they're inside the ul so it makes them appear at the same time as the whole list (because the animation is aplied to the ul).

How do I make it so items wont be affected by opacity? - Or have different levels of it. I tried applying just for the items class a different opacity strength but didn't work.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6ed4/2/)

Comment: use this selector for individual `list item` inside the list `ul li:nth-child(1)`

Comment: I don't know if you read the edited version but after writting this down I deleted it like 4 or so times because I found the answer my-self as I was writting. I managed to give a different animation to items but the opacity still affects them.

I don't know how the selector helps me (only if I could apply the selector for the ul only, and leave li's behind with it or something)

Comment: yup havent read the updated version. And what you want is that the list comes out first then the container will appear slowly using the `opacity`?

Comment: Yes! Updated the fiddle. I think it's good as it is now... Although if you know how to it's always something more to know. The problem maintains, how do I keep items from being affected by opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i get what your looking for, that when the `container` appears you want the individual `list-item` to show one by one.

```
ul li:nth-child(1){
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 10s ease;
}
ul li:nth-child(2){
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 20s ease;
}
ul li:nth-child(3){
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 30s ease;
}
#Header:hover ul li:nth-child(1) {
    opacity: 0.7;
    }

#Header:hover ul li:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0.7;
    }
#Header:hover ul li:nth-child(3) {
    opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6ed4/3/)

Comment: Yeah thanks! Meanwhile I was exploring I actually liked what I ended up doing so I'll try to get both together xD